# C char pointer with/without malloc

Tags: c, string, pointers, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *str = "This is a string";
    char *strCpy = strdup(str); // new copy with malloc in background

    printf("str: %s strCpy: %s\n", str, strCpy);
    free(strCpy);

    char *anotherStr = "This is another string";
    printf("anotherStr: %s\n", anotherStr);

    char *dynamicStr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 32);
    memcpy(dynamicStr, "test", 4+1); // length + '\0'
    printf("dynamicStr: %s\n", dynamicStr);
    free(dynamicStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the definition of `anotherStr` without malloc also possible, and what are the differences between `anotherStr` and `dynamicStr`?

Comment: it is fairly good explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible because here:

```
char *anotherStr = "This is another string";
```

The string literal("This is another string") is allocated somewhere else,
and `anotherStr` is merely set to point to that area in memory. You can't change this string for example. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Here:

```
char *dynamicStr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 32);
memcpy(dynamicStr, "test", 4);
```

Memory of given size is allocated somewhere and pointer to it is returned
which is assigned to `dynamicStr`. Then you write to that location using `memcpy`. In contrast to previous example you can write/modify content at this location. But you need to free this memory later.

ps. In above example you trigger Undefined Behaviour when printing because you used `memcpy` for copying and copied 4 characters - and forgot to copy null terminator too. Use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: Thx. So char *anotherStr = "..."; have the same behaviour as const char *str = "...";?

Comment: @leon22: I believe so yes, please also check link I provided.

Comment: @leon22 so long as you don't try to write to the characters, yes